# БД Access из-под Delphi

Tags: access, delphi, база-данных

Доброго времени суток.
Хочу узнать про подключение к БД Access через приложение из-под Delphi. Когда компилирую источником данных является БД и она находится на диске C:, в корне папки... Допустим программой будут пользоваться 1000 людей и они ставят у себя эту программу (допустим) на D:, а БД сама привязана к диску C: и просит ее туда перекинуть... 
Можно ли как-то настроить, сделать файл, которые при запуске приложения задает путь к БД и активирует все ADOConnection, Query и все такое?

Answer (score 3):

Самое простое и самое древнее решение - это брать параметры инициализации приложения из *.ini файла.
Допустим создаем файл Initial.ini в каталоге с программой с содержанием:

```
[database]
path=
```

Вот код приложения для примера, можно усложнить под собственные нужды

```
procedure TForm1.ADOConnection1BeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
var path,str:string;
begin
  if ADOConnection1.Connected then
    ADOConnection1.Close;

  with TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Initial.ini') do
  try
    path :=ReadString('batabase', 'path', '');
    if path='' then
      if OpenDialog1.Execute then
        begin
          path:=OpenDialog1.FileName;
          WriteString('batabase', 'path',path);
        end;
    str:='';
    str:=str+'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;';
    str:=str+'Password="";';
    str:=str+'Data Source='+path+';';
    str:=str+'Persist Security Info=True';
    ADOConnection1.ConnectionString:=str;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
OpenDialog1.Filter:='Файлы Access|*.mdb';
ADOConnection1.Open;
end;
```

В раздел модулей добавляем IniFiles.
    Можно по аналогии брать настройки из реестра.

Comment: Спасибо! То, что доктор прописал! Все работает так, как мне надо!

Answer (score 1):

Может поможет такой способ: при установке программы создается файл БД в указанном автором месте (например, `"C:\"`), далее в файл подгружаются данные и используются уже в нужном месте. Но лучше, сразу отвести для БД.mdb отдельное место(папку) в `"С:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Имя_программы\bin"` и туда направить запросы для работы с БД.

Поправьте, если я не прав.

Comment: мммм... Кариант, на крайняк =)

Answer (score 0):

1. Посмотреть кто поставил -1 можете в своем профиле
2. Вопрос действительно дурной, т.к. путь к базе указывается в connection string. И привязываться к абсолютным путям - плохо. А тем более хранить пользовательские данные в корне.
3. Какой интерфейс используете для работы с БД - OLE DB или ODBC? Или все-таки вообще через BDE ломитесь? Я не помню, что там в Дельфи происходит. Но на С/C++ точно есть несколько вариантов.

Comment: 1. Ок=)
2. Connection string нужно изменить (когда компилируешь программу уже в другом месте не запустишь, только по такому же пути со всеми примочками). Хотел сделать выбор пути к БД и записи переменной этого пути в connection string, а потом reactive всех подключенных ADO..
3. OLE DB

Понимаете в чем дело, в курсовом четко поставлен пункт - реализовать пользователю самостоятельное подключение к БД.

Comment: И я бы с радостью переписал на любой другой язык, но стоит реализация Delphi и не перепрешь ты нашего старого хрыща.... и сделал бы там все совершенно по другому!